# CompilerException persisted after restoring Leiningen version

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

My Leiningen project was running happily in

- Leiningen 2.5.2
- nREPL 0.2.10
- Clojure 1.8.0

Then I upgraded to Leiningen 2.7.1. Suddenly, I started getting

```
CompilerException java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default
```

error on an imported Java class on my `:resource-path`.

Not quite understanding what happened, I decided to restore back to my working environment by

```
 rm -rf ~/.m2
 rm -rf ~/.lein
 lein upgrade 2.5.2
```

Now, based on what `lein repl` tells me, I am back to my happy environment. Yet, I am still getting the same `CompilerException` on the same Java class.

This Java class has been a part of a Java application that builds separately from my Leiningen project. The Java application also builds cleanly with OpenJDK 7 and 8. Because of this, I focused on restoring my `lein repl` environment.

Did I restore the Leiningen env properly? Would you have suggestions on what else I should try?

Comment: Try deleting all the .class files, to make sure you get a clean build.

Comment: ... or a `lein clean` in general is a good idea when the WTF does not go away.

Comment: Thanks, @cfrick, @Chris Murphy. Among various (and some aimless) tinkering I attempted, I ran `ant clean` on the Java application, and `lein clean` on my Leiningen project. Didn't get me out of the hole.

Comment: How are you depending on the Java project?

Comment: The paths to Java project class and lib are included in `:resource-paths` in my `project.clj`.